# How to select an attribut that is on the "wrong" side of a OneToOne unilateral relationship with JPA criteria

Tags: jpa, select, projection, one-to-one

I've 2 entities:

```
@Entity
public class Customer{
   @Id 
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer")
   private Address address;

   @Column(name = "FIELD_1")
   private String field1;

   @Column(name = "FIELD_2")
   private String field2;
}

@Entity
public class Address{
   @Id 
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "CUST_ID")
   private Customer customer;
}
```

If I do a select to retrieve the Customer, the Adress is retrieved as well, all good.

But I want to do a projection and build a DTO, so only select field1 and field2 along with the Adress entity.

```
public class MyDTO {

    private String field1;
    private String  field2;
    private Address address;

    public MyDTO (String pField1, String pField2, Adress pAddress){
        field1 = pField1;
        field2 = pField2;
        adress = pAddress;
    }
}
```

So I've coded that DAO method :

```
public List<MyDTO > getListMyDTO() {
       CriteriaQuery<MyDTO > crit = builder.createQuery(MyDTO .class);
       Root<Customer> root = crit.from(Customer.class);
       // This is to avoid a inner join since some customer may not have an                 adress and i dont want to exclude them from my select
       root.join("address", JoinType.LEFT);

       crit.multiselect(root.get("field1"), root.get("field2"), root.get("address"));

       return em.createQuery(crit).getResultList();
}
```

em being the entity manager.
However that doesn't work and the address ends up always null.

I sorta understand this as there is no field from root pointing to the address table, but since it works when i do a select on the entity instead of a DTO, there must be a way to make this work no?

Comment: Firstly you have marked the "customer" field as OneToOne when it should be ManyToOne (other side of OneToMany). Secondly you cannot EVER select multivalued fields in JPQL or Criteria.

Comment: Hey Billy, it was my bad Customer is a OneToOne as a customer may have 0-1 address and an address always have 1 and only 1 customer.
And yeah I know i cannot select a list field. But that isn't the case here.

Comment: So if a query doesn't do like what you expected, look at the generated SQL. I can do queries of that form with the JPA provider I use (DataNucleus). Maybe the SQL will show the problem? ANy JPA provider ought to be perfectly capable of doing a join to the other object and selecting the right field(s)

Comment: Ended up having to create a "lighter" version of the entity to retrieve what I wanted. It's a workaround though.